# Fechar submenus ao clicar em outro

Tags: html, jquery, css

Tenho o seguinte menu e gostaria que quando um submenu fosse aberto, qualquer outro submenu aberto anteriormente fecharia automaticamente para não "poluir" a barra lateral, mantendo apenas um submenu aberto por vez.
Alguém tem alguma ideia do que posso implementar para resolver isso ?

```
 <nav class="sidebar">
    <div class="text">Side Menu</div>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Página inicial</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="tay-btn">Série de Taylor<span class="fas fa-caret-down first"></span></a>
            <ul class="tay-show">

            <li><a href="#">Aproximação e Erro</a></li>

            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"class="rai-btn">Raízes <span class="fas fa-caret-down second"></span></a>
            <ul class="rai-show">
                <li><a href="#">Bissecção</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Falsa posição</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Newton-Raphson</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Secante</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="sis-btn">Sistemas lineares<span class="fas fa-caret-down third"></span></a>
            <ul class="sis-show">
                <li><a href="#">Sistemas triangulares</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Método de Gauss</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Decomposição LU</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Jacobi</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Gauss-Seidel</a></li>
            </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="mmq-btn">MMQ<span class="fas fa-caret-down fourth"></span></a>
            <ul class="mmq-show">
                <li><a href="#">Regressão linear</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Regressão polinomial</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Caso Geral</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="inter-btn">Interpolação<span class="fas fa-caret-down fifth"></span></a>
            <ul class="inter-show">
                <li><a href="#">Lagrange</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Newton</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#" class="integ-btn">Integração<span class="fas fa-caret-down sixth"></span></a>
            <ul class="integ-show">
                <li><a href="#">Regra do trapézio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Simpson 1/3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Simpson 3/8</a></li>
            </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="edo-btn">EDOs<span class="fas fa-caret-down seventh"></span></a>
            <ul class="edo-show">
                <li><a href="#">Método de Euler</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Método de Geun</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Método do Ponto Médio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Métodos de Runge-Kutta</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>

</nav>
```

e o script jquery está assim:

```
 <script>
    $('.tay-btn').click(function(){
        $('nav ul .tay-show').toggleClass("show");
        $('nav ul .first').toggleClass("rotate");
      });
    $('.rai-btn').click(function(){
        $('nav ul .rai-show').toggleClass("show1");
        $('nav ul .second').toggleClass("rotate");
      });
      $('.sis-btn').click(function(){
        $('nav ul .sis-show').toggleClass("show2");
        $('nav ul .third').toggleClass("rotate");
      });
      $('.mmq-btn').click(function(){
        $('nav ul .mmq-show').toggleClass("show3");
        $('nav ul .fourth').toggleClass("rotate");
      });
      $('.inter-btn').click(function(){
        $('nav ul .inter-show').toggleClass("show4");
        $('nav ul .fifth').toggleClass("rotate");
      });
      $('.integ-btn').click(function(){
        $('nav ul .integ-show').toggleClass("show5");
        $('nav ul .sixth').toggleClass("rotate");
      });
      $('.edo-btn').click(function(){
        $('nav ul .edo-show').toggleClass("show6");
        $('nav ul .seventh').toggleClass("rotate");
      });


</script>
```

E o css:

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    user-select: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.sidebar
{
    position: fixed;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background: #1b1b1b;
}

.sidebar .text
{
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 65px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #1e1e1e;
    letter-spacing: 1px;

}

nav ul
{
    background: #1b1b1b;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
}

nav ul li
{
    line-height: 60px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}
nav ul li a
{
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    font-weight: 500;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border-left: 3px solid transparent;
}

nav ul li a:hover
{
    color: cyan;
    background: #1e1e1e;
    border-left-color: cyan;

}

nav ul ul
{
    position: static;
    display: none;

}

nav ul ul li
{
    position: static;
    line-height: 42px;
    border-bottom: none;

}

nav ul ul li a
{
   font-size: 14px;
    color: #e6e6e6;
    padding-left: 45px;
}

nav ul li a span
{
  position: absolute; 
  top: 50%;
  right: 20px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 22px;
  transition: transform 0.4s;

}

nav ul li a span.rotate
{
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-180deg);
}

nav ul .tay-show.show
{
   display:block; 
}

nav ul .rai-show.show1
{
   display:block; 
}

nav ul .sis-show.show2
{
   display:block;  
}

nav ul .mmq-show.show3
{
   display:block;

}
nav ul .inter-show.show4
{
   display:block;   
}

nav ul .integ-show.show5
{
   display:block;   
}
nav ul .edo-show.show6
{
   display:block; 

}
```

Comment: Amigo, edita sua pergunta. Não dá pra entender exatamente sua dúvida. Provavelmente seu post será fechado se continuar assim.

Comment: Pronto. Espero que tenha ficado mais claro

Comment: Faltou colocar o CSS também.

Comment: o <nav> acabou ficando antes do ```. Agora está aparecendo. Acrescentei o css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daria pra simplificar o código criando apenas uma classe para todos os toggle, sem ter que criar um evento click para cada classe, mas para resolver o problema em questão, basta acrescentar o código abaixo, que remove a classe `.show` de todas `<ul>` dentro de `.sidebar`, exceto da `<ul>` relacionada ao item do menu clicado:

```
$(".sidebar li a").click(function(){
   $(".fas", this) // seleciona o span.fas dentro do link clicado
   .toggleClass("rotate") // adiciona ou remove a classe
   .parent() // seleciona o pai do span, no caso o link <a>
   .next() // seleciona o elemento adjacente, no caso o <ul>
   .toggleClass("show"); // adiciona ou remova a classe

   $(".sidebar li a") // seleciona todos os <a>
   .not(this) // exceto ele próprio
   .next() // seleciona o elemento adjacente, no caso o <ul>
   .removeClass("show") // remove a classe
   .prev() // volta a selecionar o <a>
   .find(".fas") // seleciona o span.fas
   .removeClass("rotate"); // remove a classe
});
```

E usar apenas uma classe `.show` (não precisa repetir show1, show2 etc.):

```
nav.sidebar ul.show
{
   display:block; 
}
```

**Amostra:**

```js
$(".sidebar li a").click(function(){
   $(".fas", this)
   .toggleClass("rotate")
   .parent()
   .next()
   .toggleClass("show");

   $(".sidebar li a")
   .not(this)
   .next()
   .removeClass("show")
   .prev()
   .find(".fas")
   .removeClass("rotate");
});
```

```css
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    user-select: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.sidebar
{
    position: fixed;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background: #1b1b1b;
}

.sidebar .text
{
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 65px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #1e1e1e;
    letter-spacing: 1px;

}

nav ul
{
    background: #1b1b1b;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
}

nav ul li
{
    line-height: 60px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}
nav ul li a
{
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    font-weight: 500;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border-left: 3px solid transparent;
}

nav ul li a:hover
{
    color: cyan;
    background: #1e1e1e;
    border-left-color: cyan;

}

nav ul ul
{
    position: static;
    display: none;

}

nav ul ul li
{
    position: static;
    line-height: 42px;
    border-bottom: none;

}

nav ul ul li a
{
   font-size: 14px;
    color: #e6e6e6;
    padding-left: 45px;
}

nav ul li a span
{
  position: absolute; 
  top: 50%;
  right: 20px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 22px;
  transition: transform 0.4s;

}

nav ul li a span.rotate
{
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-180deg);
}

nav.sidebar ul.show
{
   display:block; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="sidebar">
<div class="text">Side Menu</div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Página inicial</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="tay-btn">Série de Taylor<span class="fas fa-caret-down first"></span></a>
            <ul class="tay-show">

            <li><a href="#">Aproximação e Erro</a></li>

            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"class="rai-btn">Raízes <span class="fas fa-caret-down second"></span></a>
            <ul class="rai-show">
                <li><a href="#">Bissecção</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Falsa posição</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Newton-Raphson</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Secante</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="sis-btn">Sistemas lineares<span class="fas fa-caret-down third"></span></a>
            <ul class="sis-show">
                <li><a href="#">Sistemas triangulares</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Método de Gauss</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Decomposição LU</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Jacobi</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Gauss-Seidel</a></li>
            </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="mmq-btn">MMQ<span class="fas fa-caret-down fourth"></span></a>
            <ul class="mmq-show">
                <li><a href="#">Regressão linear</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Regressão polinomial</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Caso Geral</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="inter-btn">Interpolação<span class="fas fa-caret-down fifth"></span></a>
            <ul class="inter-show">
                <li><a href="#">Lagrange</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Newton</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#" class="integ-btn">Integração<span class="fas fa-caret-down sixth"></span></a>
            <ul class="integ-show">
                <li><a href="#">Regra do trapézio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Simpson 1/3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Simpson 3/8</a></li>
            </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="edo-btn">EDOs<span class="fas fa-caret-down seventh"></span></a>
            <ul class="edo-show">
                <li><a href="#">Método de Euler</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Método de Geun</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Método do Ponto Médio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Métodos de Runge-Kutta</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas soluções. Ambas funcionaram e me ajudaram a entender melhor como o jquery funciona. Sou iniciante no meio e muitas vezes é difícil extrair informações de outros códigos/dúvidas e conseguir implementar no próprio projeto.

Comment: Estou editando a resposta para ficar mais simples.

Comment: Dá uma olhada agora como ficou mais simples. Não é necessário aquele monte de código e classes.

Answer (score 0):

Se o que faz o menu abrir, é a class '`show`' . Basta remover a class dos menus abertos. Acredito que algo como isso resolveria seu problema:

- Coloquei id para referência em casa menu:

```html
<li><a href="#" class="tay-btn">Série de Taylor<span id="ico" class="fas fa-caret-down first"></span></a>
            <ul class="tay-show"  id="menu">

            <li><a href="#">Aproximação e Erro</a></li>

            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"class="rai-btn">Raízes <span id="ico1" class="fas fa-caret-down second"></span></a>
            <ul class="rai-show" id="menu1">
                <li><a href="#">Bissecção</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Falsa posição</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Newton-Raphson</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Secante</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="sis-btn">Sistemas lineares<span id="ico2" class="fas fa-caret-down third"></span></a>
            <ul class="sis-show" id="menu2">
                <li><a href="#">Sistemas triangulares</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Método de Gauss</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Decomposição LU</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Jacobi</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Gauss-Seidel</a></li>
            </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="mmq-btn">MMQ<span id="ico3" class="fas fa-caret-down fourth"></span></a>
            <ul class="mmq-show" id="menu3">
                <li><a href="#">Regressão linear</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Regressão polinomial</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Caso Geral</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="inter-btn">Interpolação<span id="ico4" class="fas fa-caret-down fifth"></span></a>
            <ul class="inter-show" id="menu4">
                <li><a href="#">Lagrange</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Newton</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#" class="integ-btn">Integração<span id="ico5" class="fas fa-caret-down sixth"></span></a>
            <ul class="integ-show" id="menu5">
                <li><a href="#">Regra do trapézio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Simpson 1/3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Simpson 3/8</a></li>
            </ul>

        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="edo-btn">EDOs<span id="ico6" class="fas fa-caret-down seventh"></span></a>
            <ul class="edo-show" id="menu6">
                <li><a href="#">Método de Euler</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Método de Geun</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Método do Ponto Médio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Métodos de Runge-Kutta</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

Fiz uma função para fechar os menus antes de abrir outro:

```js
 <script>
    function fechaMenus(){
      $('#menu').removeClass('show');
      $('#ico').removeClass('rotate');

      $('#menu1').removeClass('show1');
      $('#ico1').removeClass('rotate');

      $('#menu2').removeClass('show2');
      $('#ico2').removeClass('rotate');

      $('#menu3').removeClass('show3');
      $('#ico3').removeClass('rotate');

      $('#menu4').removeClass('show4');
      $('#ico4').removeClass('rotate');

      $('#menu5').removeClass('show5');
      $('#ico5').removeClass('rotate');

      $('#menu6').removeClass('show6');
      $('#ico6').removeClass('rotate');
    }

    $('.tay-btn').click(function(){
        this.fechaMenus();
        $('nav ul .tay-show').toggleClass("show");
        $('nav ul .first').toggleClass("rotate");
      });
    $('.rai-btn').click(function(){
        this.fechaMenus();
        $('nav ul .rai-show').toggleClass("show1");
        $('nav ul .second').toggleClass("rotate");
      });
      $('.sis-btn').click(function(){
        this.fechaMenus();
        $('nav ul .sis-show').toggleClass("show2");
        $('nav ul .third').toggleClass("rotate");
      });
      $('.mmq-btn').click(function(){
        this.fechaMenus();
        $('nav ul .mmq-show').toggleClass("show3");
        $('nav ul .fourth').toggleClass("rotate");
      });
      $('.inter-btn').click(function(){
        this.fechaMenus();
        $('nav ul .inter-show').toggleClass("show4");
        $('nav ul .fifth').toggleClass("rotate");
      });
      $('.integ-btn').click(function(){
        this.fechaMenus();
        $('nav ul .integ-show').toggleClass("show5");
        $('nav ul .sixth').toggleClass("rotate");
      });
      $('.edo-btn').click(function(){
        this.fechaMenus();
        $('nav ul .edo-show').toggleClass("show6");
        $('nav ul .seventh').toggleClass("rotate");
      });


</script>
```

Isso provavelmente resolve seu problema. Qualquer dúvida deixa nos comentários.